# Updating Table after CRUD action in React?

Tags: reactjs, crud

I'm very new to React and I'm struggling a bit with understanding how it all works.

I have two components, a table and a form (in  a popup) to add/delete records. When I add a new record, the table shows a new line, however there's no text until i hit refresh. Similarly when I update a record I also have to hit refresh to see the changes in the table.

My Client.js component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    clientList: state.client.list
})

const mapActionToProps = {
    getAllClients: actions.getAll,
    createClient: actions.create,
    updateClient: actions.update
}

const headCells = [
    { id: 'name', label: 'Client Name' },
    { id: 'hourlyRate', label: 'Hourly Rate' },
    { id: 'contactName', label: 'Contact Name' },
    { id: 'contactEmail', label: 'Contact Email' },
    { id: 'actions', label: "Actions", disableSorting: true }
]

const Clients = (props) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [recordForEdit, setRecordForEdit] = useState(null);
    const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getAllClients()
    }, [])

    const {
        TblContainer,
        TblHead,
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting
    } = Table(props.clientList, headCells, filterFunction);

    const addOrEdit = (client, resetForm) => {
        if(client.clientID == null) 
            props.createClient(client)
        else
            props.updateClient(client.clientID, client)
        resetForm()
        setRecordForEdit(null)
        setOpenPopup(false)
        props.getAllClients()
    }

    const openInPopup =  item => {
        setRecordForEdit(item)
        setOpenPopup(true)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <PageHeader
                title='Clients'
                subTitle='Client management'
                icon={<ApartmentIcon fontSize="large" />} />
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Controls.Input
                        label="Search"
                        className={classes.searchInput}
                        InputProps={{
                            startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">
                                <Search />
                            </InputAdornment>)
                        }}
                        onChange={handleSearch}
                    />
                    <Controls.Button
                        text="Add new"
                        variant="outlined"
                        startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                        className={classes.newButton}
                        onClick={() => {setOpenPopup(true); setRecordForEdit(null);}}
                    />
                </Toolbar>

                <TblContainer>
                    <TblHead></TblHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {
                            recordsAfterPagingAndSorting().map((record) => {
                                return (<TableRow key={record.clientID}>
                                    <TableCell>{record.name}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{record.hourlyRate}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{record.contactName}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{record.contactEmail}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Controls.ActionButton 
                                        color="primary"
                                        onClick={() => {openInPopup(record)}}>
                                            <Edit fontSize="small" />
                                        </Controls.ActionButton>
                                        <Controls.ActionButton color="secondary">
                                            <Close fontSize="small" />
                                        </Controls.ActionButton>

                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>)
                            })
                        }
                    </TableBody>
                </TblContainer>
                <TblPagination />
            </Paper>
            <Popup
                openPopup={openPopup}
                setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}
                title="Add client"
                >
                <ClientForm
                    addOrEdit={addOrEdit} 
                    recordForEdit={recordForEdit}/>
            </Popup>
        </>
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(Clients)
```

addOrEdit gets called from my ClientForm in a handleSubmit call.

And my reusable table component:

```
export default function Table(records, headCells, filterFunction) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const pages = [25, 10, 5]
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(pages[page]);
    const [order, setOrder] = useState()
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState()


    const TblContainer = props => (
        <MuiTable className={classes.table}>
            {props.children}
        </MuiTable>
    )

    const TblHead = props => {

        const handleSortRequest = cellId => {
            const isAsc = orderBy === cellId && order === "asc";
            setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
            setOrderBy(cellId)
        }

        return (<TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                {
                    headCells.map(headCell => (<TableCell key={headCell.id}
                        sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}>
                        {headCell.disableSorting ? headCell.label :
                            <TableSortLabel
                                active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                                onClick={() => { handleSortRequest(headCell.id) }}>
                                {headCell.label}
                            </TableSortLabel>
                        }
                    </TableCell>))
                }
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>)
    }

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    }

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    }

    const TblPagination = props => (<TablePagination
        component="div"
        page={page}
        rowsPerPageOptions={pages}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        count={records.length}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage} />)

    // From MaterialUI table sort
    function tableSort(array, comparator) {
        const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
        stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
            const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
            if (order !== 0) return order;
            return a[1] - b[1];
        });
        return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
    }

    // From MaterialUI table sort
    function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
        return order === 'desc'
            ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
            : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    }

    // From MaterialUI table sort
    function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
        if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    const recordsAfterPagingAndSorting = () => {
        return tableSort(filterFunction.fn(records), getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage)
    }

    return {
        TblContainer,
        TblHead,
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting
    }
}
```

I've been trying to add a const [records, setRecords] and storing props.clientLIst in that and then calling setRecords(props.clientList) in addOrUpdate - but I couldn't get that to work either.

It feels like I'm close to the answer, but I just can't see it - any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

For the issue you describe: Seems like you are setting the state which adds or edits the record in the wrong component.
If you set it upper in a component which wraps both table and form component and pass it down as a prop or through redux, when you change the state, both components will be re-rendered without need to refresh manually.